# How to copy a folder from machine to external HDD in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

**Source:** /media/pcadmin/744EA3514EA30B46/Users/Pawankumar/android-sdks

**Destination:** /media/pcadmin/Seagate Expansion Drive/Android

but when i do **sudo cp -a /media/pcadmin/744EA3514EA30B46/Users/Pawankumar/android-sdks /media/pcadmin/Seagate Expansion Drive/Android**

I get this error 
**`cp: target ‘Drive/Android’ is not a directory`**

It's Hard Drive name space causing problem(Seagate Expansion Drive), my folder is a big chunk of 79 GB file with over 1 million files.

What would be proper command to do this ?

**EDIT:**

sudo cp -a /media/pcadmin/744EA3514EA30B46/Users/Pawankumar/android-sdks /media/pcadmin/Seagate\ Expansion\ Drive

Its working now.

Comment: You need to quote or escape the path if it contains spaces.

Comment: sudo cp -a /media/pcadmin/744EA3514EA30B46/Users/Pawankumar/android-sdks /media/pcadmin/Seagate /Expansion /Drive
cp: target ‘/Drive’ is not a directory

Comment: Do you understand the difference between forward slash (/) and back slash (\\) ? Also note that the back slash goes *before* the character that you want to escape.

Comment: Yeas, i know man. I got this working. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you consult the man cp you will see :

> cp [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY

so in your command if think all this part is SOURCE

> /media/pcadmin/744EA3514EA30B46/Users/Pawankumar/android-sdks
>   /media/pcadmin/Seagate Expansion

and this is DIRECTORY

> Drive/Android

So you must escape the 'space' in

> /media/pcadmin/Seagate\ Expansion\ Drive/Android